# ClassCastException for onItemClick variable

Tags: android, string, classcastexception, pid, onitemclick

I am getting a ClassCastException for the pid variable that I am trying to show on screen. I know that the item at the onclick position is a string that is casting to RunningAppProcessInfo which is causing the exception, but I cant figure out how I can get the pid without using it though.

Here is my code

```
  ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  List<RunningAppProcessInfo> list = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

  ArrayList<String> info = new ArrayList<>();
  for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo p : list) {
      info.add(p.processName);
  }

  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, info);
  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);

  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          int  uid = ((RunningAppProcessInfo)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).pid;
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),uid,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no. The way you've initialized your adapter, the item is going to be the process name, not the process ID. It certainly won't be an instance of `RunningAppProcessInfo`. If you want your items to be process IDs, redefine your adapter as follows:

```
ArrayList<Integer> info = new ArrayList<>();
for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo p : list) {
    info.add(p.pid); // not p.processName
}

ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, info);
```

and then retrieve it with:

```
int uid = (Integer) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

If you need both, you'll have to define your own class that holds both the process name and the ID:

```
class Info {
    final String processName;
    final int pid;
    Info(String processName, int pid) {
        this.processName = processName;
        this.pid = pid;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return processName;
    }
}
ArrayList<Info> info = new ArrayList<>();
for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo p : list) {
    info.add(new Info(p.processName, p.pid));
}

ArrayAdapter<Info> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, info);
```

and retrieve it with:

```
int uid = ((Info)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).pid;
```

You might be tempted to write:

```
ArrayList<RunningAppProcessInfo> info = new ArrayList<>();
for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo p : list) {
    info.add(p);
}

ArrayAdapter<RunningAppProcessInfo> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, info);
```

and keep your original retrieval code, but unfortunately, `RunningAppProcessInfo` doesn't have a usable `toString()` method for the adapter to use, so you're going to have to write a container class one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

parent.getItemAtPosition(position) will actually return the item of list you provided in the ArrayAdapter constructor, so it is a String, and then of course you will get a classCastException when you try to cast this String to a RunningAppProcessInfo.

My suggestion is to use a custom adapter instead of ArrayAdapter directly. Here is a sample code I wrote for your reference:

```
public class ProcessSampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> mAppProcInfos;

public ProcessSampleAdapter(Context context, List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> list) {
    mContext = context;
    mAppProcInfos = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mAppProcInfos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mAppProcInfos.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup root) {
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);

    TextView textV = (TextView)convertView;
    textV.setText(mAppProcInfos.get(position).processName);

    return convertView;
}

}
```

And by the way, since uid is an int, so don't serve it to makeToast method directly, otherwise instead of showing uid, it will try to look for a String resource with id of uid.